# How start aiohttp app in multiple workers?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want aiohttp app running on number of processes.

Tornado has

```
server = HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8888)
server.start(0)
```

for starting workers (0 - cpu cores). I know about gunicorn. But i want server embeded into application.

Found https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#server how use it?

Answer (score 1):

According [to the documentation for aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/deployment.html), running on multiple cores in a single application isn't supported.

> **Standalone**
>
> Just call `aiohttp.web.run_app()` function passing
> `aiohttp.web.Application` instance.
>
> The method is very simple and could be the best solution in some
> trivial cases. But it does not utilize all CPU cores.
>
> For *running multiple aiohttp server instances use reverse proxies*.

This means that it's outside of the responsibility of aiohttp to support multiple processes; instead leaving that part to [supervisord (which nginx can then connect to in a round-robin fashion)](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/deployment.html#nginx-configuration) or [gunicorn w/nginx](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/deployment.html#nginx-gunicorn).

Comment: nginx,  supervisord, gunicorn is architecture depended binaries...

I will try to use `server` protocol factory on shared socket...

Comment: gunicorn will install the correct binary as a dependency in your application when the other dependencies are installed through PyPi / pip.

Comment: maybe... but i also have non wsgi servers and want a know way to share sockets..